# How do I use a hyperlink in link variable?

Tags: php, get

I'm using `$_GET['link']` to recieve the link...

but the link has `&`'s in it causing the variable to be read incorrectly.

How do I do this?

this is the link...

http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=172860651&id=162881967&hash=1864975b71a6085a&hd=1

for reference.

Thanks.

Comment: so, your script is retrieving the link via GET? You need to urlencode() the link then use urldecode() in your script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In writing the link use `urlencode` then in reading the link use `urldecode`:

```
<a href="http://example.com/file.php?link=<?php echo urlencode($link);?>">link</a>

<?php
   $link = urldecode($_GET['link']);    
   echo $link;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use PHP's urlencode (http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) when you create the link and and then use urldecode (http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) on $_GET['link'] to get the correct value.

Comment: [http://php.net/urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) (nice URL rewriting ;-) This would also use the browser language when opening php.net

Comment: Hehe, yeah! That's a nice touch! :)