# redirector or anony clone

Tags: php, redirect, referrer

I need to do a dynamic redirect based on anything past the ? in the URL.

So for example. If i send a link like:

http://go.com?http://link1.com

go.com loads a page which has a 15 second loading page. This page will have some html on it. If the person does nothing it just redirects to link1.com after 15 seconds.

This action should happen with ANY url i add after the question mark

http://go.com?http://link2.com
http://go.com?http://link5.com
etc

Here is the code i have found, but its not working.

```
<?php
$delay = "15"; # how many seconds expire before automatic redirect
$site = $_GET['url']; ?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $delay; ?>;url=http://<?php echo $site; ?>">
</head>
<body>
  redirecting you to <?php echo $site; ?> in <?php echo $delay; ?> seconds ...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Either format your URL to `http://go.com/?url=http://link1.com` or use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to access it.

Take into account URL encoding the URL you are redirecting to; otherwise, parts of the destination URL could be misunderstood by the browser as parts of the go.com URL, and you'll end up with odd errors and broken redirects. Take a look at [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php):

**When creating the link the user clicks to get to the redirection page**

```
<a href="http://go.com?<?=urlencode("http://link1.com/?a=b&c=d#e")?>">Go to Link1!</a>
```

This turns the example target URL `http://link1.com/?a=b&c=d#e` to `http%3A%2F%2Flink1.com%2F%3Fa%3Db%26c%3Dd%23e`, so that any of the : / ? & # characters in the `link1.com` URL cannot affect the behavior of the `go.com` page.

**When getting the link on the redirection page**

```
$site = urldecode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

This uses my suggested `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to get the destination URL instead of `$_GET['url']`, wrapped in `urldecode()` to undo what we did in the previous step, so that the garglemesh generated by `urlencode()` will be turned back into a normal looking URL we can use in the `meta` tag.

Also, based on this code, you seem to have the `http://` in both your redirector page URL and the redirecting `meta` tag, resulting in an attempt to redirect to `http://http://link1.com`. Remove the `http://` from the meta tag.

Furthermore, if you do insist on a redirecting page (which are annoying), please please please add a "Click here to redirect instantly" link to the page for those of us who don't have 15 seconds to wait staring at nothing of importance.

Comment: thanks so much emphram. Can you give/show me some usage examples with urlencode()?

I'm a newb..

Comment: I updated my answer to expand on the usage of `urlencode()` and `urldecode()`, I hope you understand it better now. If you find my or the others' answers helpful, remember to upvote and mark as answer with the controls on the left! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use urlencode and urldecode functions to void any problem with special characters in the destination url. You may refer to this question: [How do I use a hyperlink in link variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663393/how-do-i-use-a-hyperlink-in-link-variable/13663446#13663446)

Answer (score 0):

**Working Code**

```
<?php
$delay = 5; # how many seconds expire before automatic redirect
$delayMili = $delay * 1000; //converting it to miliseconds
$site = $_GET['url'];
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/JavaScript'>
            setTimeout('window.location="<?php echo $site; ?>"',<?php echo $delayMili;?>)
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        redirecting you to <?php echo $site; ?> in <?php echo $delay; ?> seconds ...</p>
</body>
</html>
```